# Change sjTable formatting?

Tags: r, kable

I have an sjTable below that I want to convert to a data table so I can use the kable function for better formatting. I tried several ways such as using `data.table(tbl)` but it doesn't work.

Or if anyone knows how I can format this sjTable to look similar to a kable table using CSS (in terms of font, spacing, color theme), that would also be much appreciated. Essentially I want to change the font to a default kable table, and want the table bellow to be bigger/ more spacing between columns and rows in an R markdown HTML output.

```
# load package
library(sjPlot)
library(haven)

# sample data
data("efc")
efc <- as_factor(efc, c161sex, c172code)

m1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

tbl <- tab_model(m1, show.obs=FALSE)
tbl
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extracting table from `tab_model` extract the values from the model itself. For example, `broom::tidy` gives you most of the values that you want.

```
broom::tidy(m1)

#   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 (Intercept)   90.1      6.17      14.6   5.07e-43
#2 c160age       -0.222    0.0711    -3.12  1.90e- 3
#3 c12hour       -0.278    0.0186   -14.9   1.15e-44
#4 c161sex       -0.262    2.09      -0.125 9.00e- 1
#5 c172code      -0.762    1.42      -0.537 5.92e- 1
```

You can change the labels if needed from this and use it in `kable`.